# I am having problem in Upgrading Magento Version from 2.2.1 to 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2.4

PLease find my composer.json file.

```
{
"name": "magento/magento2ce",
"description": "Magento 2 (Open Source)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.2.1-dev",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "php": "7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "^2.7.7",
    "zendframework/zend-code": "^3.1.0",
    "zendframework/zend-server": "^2.6.1",
    "zendframework/zend-soap": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-uri": "^2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-validator": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-crypt": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-console": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "^2.7",
    "zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.6.3",
    "zendframework/zend-text": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-i18n": "^2.7.3",
    "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "^2.6.3",
    "zendframework/zend-view": "^2.8.1",
    "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "^2.7.8",
    "zendframework/zend-json": "^2.6.1",
    "zendframework/zend-config": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-form": "^2.10.0",
    "zendframework/zend-di": "^2.6.1",
    "zendframework/zend-serializer": "^2.7.2",
    "zendframework/zend-log": "^2.9.1",
    "zendframework/zend-http": "^2.6.0",
    "zendframework/zend-db": "^2.8.2",
    "zendframework/zend-captcha": "^2.7.1",
    "zendframework/zend-session": "^2.7.3",
    "magento/zendframework1": "~1.13.0",
    "colinmollenhour/credis": "1.8.2",
    "colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract": "1.3.4",
    "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis": "1.10.2",
    "colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file": "1.4",
    "composer/composer": "1.4.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
    "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.7.0",
    "pelago/emogrifier": "0.1.1",
    "tubalmartin/cssmin": "4.1.0",
    "magento/magento-composer-installer": ">=0.1.11",
    "braintree/braintree_php": "3.22.0",
    "symfony/console": "~2.3, !=2.7.0",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "~2.1",
    "symfony/process": "~2.1",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.*",
    "tedivm/jshrink": "~1.1.0",
    "magento/composer": "~1.2.0",
    "lib-libxml": "*",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-spl": "*",
    "ext-dom": "*",
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "ext-mcrypt": "*",
    "ext-hash": "*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-intl": "*",
    "ext-xsl": "*",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
    "ext-soap": "*",
    "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
    "ramsey/uuid": "3.6.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.0.1",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.1.1",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
},
"replace": {
    "magento/module-marketplace": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-admin-notification": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-authorization": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-authorizenet": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-backend": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-backup": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-braintree": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-bundle": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-cache-invalidate": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-captcha": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog": "102.0.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-search": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-catalog-widget": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-checkout": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-checkout-agreements": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-cms": "102.0.0",
    "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-config": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-configurable-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-configurable-product": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-configurable-product-sales": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-contact": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-cookie": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-cron": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-currency-symbol": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-customer": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-customer-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-deploy": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-developer": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-dhl": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-directory": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-downloadable": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-eav": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-email": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-encryption-key": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-fedex": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-gift-message": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-google-adwords": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-google-analytics": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-google-optimizer": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-grouped-product": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-indexer": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-integration": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-layered-navigation": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-media-storage": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-msrp": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-multishipping": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-newsletter": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-offline-payments": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-offline-shipping": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-page-cache": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-payment": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-paypal": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-persistent": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-product-alert": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-product-video": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-quote": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-reports": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-require-js": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-review": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-robots": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-rss": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-rule": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-sales": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-sales-inventory": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-sales-rule": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-sales-sequence": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-sample-data": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-search": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-security": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-send-friend": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-shipping": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-signifyd": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-sitemap": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-store": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-swagger": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-swatches": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-tax": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-tax-import-export": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-theme": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-translation": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-ui": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-ups": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-url-rewrite": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-user": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-usps": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-variable": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-vault": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-version": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-webapi": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-webapi-security": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-weee": "100.2.0",
    "magento/module-widget": "101.0.0",
    "magento/module-wishlist": "101.0.0",
    "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "100.2.0",
    "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.2.0",
    "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-de_de": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-en_us": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-es_es": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-fr_fr": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-nl_nl": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-pt_br": "100.2.0",
    "magento/language-zh_hans_cn": "100.2.0",
    "magento/framework": "101.0.0",
    "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "1.4.3",
    "components/jquery": "1.11.0",
    "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "5.6.14",
    "components/jqueryui": "1.10.4",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.1.0",
    "tinymce/tinymce": "3.4.7"
},
"extra": {
    "component_paths": {
        "trentrichardson/jquery-timepicker-addon": "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
        "components/jquery": [
            "lib/web/jquery.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery.min.js",
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery-migrate.js"
        ],
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "lib/web/jquery/fileUploader",
        "components/jqueryui": [
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery-ui.js"
        ],
        "twbs/bootstrap": [
            "lib/web/jquery/jquery.tabs.js"
        ],
        "tinymce/tinymce": "lib/web/tiny_mce"
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

}

When upgrading composer using 
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.4 --no-update
shows error 
[InvalidArgumentException]
Couldnot find the matching version of package magento/product-community-edition

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps, I'm sure there are people out there who could explain it in more detail as to exactly why its failing.

You could try manually adding it to your composer.json file. I have never had any issues updating from 2.2.1 to 2.2.4 with all of my clients.

Something similar to below? I'm not an expert when it comes to composer but I have never had any issues when manually editing it. Once you have edited the file it should be as simple as running "composer update".

```
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.2.4",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.4",
},
```